# Simple C++ Summing Program

Tags: c++, double

This is my first time using C++ and I am writing a small program to sum up to ten numbers (doubles) that will be entered in the command prompt.

I have written the following code and I cannot figure out why it will not produce the desired result.

```
int main()
{
    double num[10];
    double sum = 0;
    int i;
    int n = 10;

    while (scanf_s("%lf", &num) != EOF)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            scanf_s("%lf", &num);
            sum = sum + num[i];
        }
    }

    cout << sum;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The data entry is terminated with a control D.
In my eyes it should run fine but it doesn't.  Could someone please give me some pointers for solving this, I don't just want to be told the correct way I would rather learn it myself.

Comment: The `scanf` function returns the number of items that were input successfully, not EOF.

Comment: why do you need the outer while loop when you have the inner for loop to ask the number to enter 10 times ?

Comment: Also, `num` is an array.  The `scanf` function needs the address of an array slot to read into, not the address of the entire array.

Comment: From using `scanf_s` I assume you are using MSVS as compiler on Windows. What makes you think Ctrl+D should terminate input then? EOF on Windows is Ctrl+Z if I am not mistaken.

Comment: You read the number of elements into a variable `num`, but you use `n` as the limit.   What purpose is the first read in the `while` loop's expression?

Comment: You don't check the 2nd `scanf` for failure.

Comment: @MooingDuck C++ is a mess, but it's not possible that it gives you problems even trying to do a simple sum with some input.

Comment: Should it not be sscanf()?

Comment: Thanks for all the constructive criticism!, I really did learn quite a lot from it, I used cin and just used one while loop and everything worked out nicely in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that &num is the address of the array.  SO you read your value always in `num[0]` meaning that `num[i]`is random in most of the cases.

Try to change your loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n && (cin>>num[i]); ++i)
{
    sum = sum + num[i];
}
```

Comment: I actually used a while loop in the end but thanks for you answer anyways